# Using "New" in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I was introduced to NodeJS a few months ago. I want to learn enough to write a useful application that can handle a moderate load. I'm taking my time, studying eBooks, websites, and code. My background is casual programming in various languages including PHP. I've been looking at source code for various Node packages available, simply to learn and see best practices. Some in particular are the various websocket packages available. I notice that NodeJS authors tend to use an object oriented method of structuring their code, such that objects are instantiated dynamically, for example:

```
var wsRequest = new WebSocketRequest(someParams);
var wsConnection = new WebSocketConnection(someParams);
var wsFrame = new WebSocketFrame(someParams);
```

Requests beget Connections, Connections beget Frames.

That's logical to me as the advantages of OOP. But in the past such programs I've written in other languages have had instances of classes created slowly; once, or at the pace of a user's input. Here though, complex objects are created much faster, at the pace of perhaps hundreds or more per second depending on the the load of the website. In addition, I assume the garbage collector has to work diligently to clean stuff up. My question is, would a *procedural* approach to writing Node applications be more performant than the liberal use of "new" in server callbacks, creating complex objects on the fly? or is any advantage minuscule compared to the advantages of OOP.

Comment: Do know that in JavaScript, there are many more ways to create object than `new`. There are array literals (`[]`), object literals (`{}`), functions (`function() {}`), strings `'abc'`, and even numbers (`123`). I would not be surprised if OOP added little to total allocations.

Answer (score 0):

Such objects are very very cheap if they use prototypes*. Look past the syntax - if you are not careful you are probably creating functions inside other functions, those always create very expensive objects every time.

Worst offender is something like this:

```
function something() {
     var a;
     var b = function() {
         use(a);
     }.bind(this);
}
```

Every time you call `something()` you create a function object, a closure and then bound function. All of these in total cost easily **25-50** normal light-weight objects like `WebSocketFrame`. You might even do the above in a loop or such.

*If they are not using prototypes, you create a function object for each method for each instance and the amount of garbage will be **massive** indeed*.

---

Some numbers:

```
object        32-bit                      64-bit

normal        12+4 for each field         24+8 for each field
function      36                          72
closure       70                          140
bound-closure 300                         600
```

For example a class with 5 fields and 30 methods implemented with prototypes:

```
12 + 4*5 = 32 bytes per instance
```

If it was not implemented with prototypes:

```
12 + 4*5 + 30 * 36 = 1112 bytes per instance (or 2224 on 64-bit)
```

---

In canonical PHP implementation objects are implemented as hash tables and are slow for that reason. If you use constructors and prototypes and objects normally in JS they will be more like C++ and Java objects - with only 4 bytes larger header than Java objects in HotSpot actually.